# Writing to a file with xyz format

Tags: python, file-io

I want to write x points and y points in a trajectory file with the xyz format. But I am a beginner in python, and this code gives the error  `unexpected character after line continuation character`.  The first line is number of atoms, second line is a comment, and third line is coordinates.

```
xyz.close()
```

Comment: Check the syntax highlighting ;-)

Comment: in the line `xyz.write('%s,%8x,%8y,%8z'\'n%(xpoints,ypoints,0)')` you have an unbalanced abount of quotes since you escape one with a backslash.

Comment: What's the `'\'n` doing in `xyz.write(...)`? I think that might be the issue, because `\ ` is the line continuation character. Perhaps you meant `xyz.write('%s...%8z\n' % (...))`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line, with the character `\` (which python may think is a line continuation character in certain contexts). When you fix that, you'll also have the problem that `%8x` and `%8z` are illegal formatting characters. I don't know exactly what you want, but `%s` might work.

To solve those two problems, change this:

```
xyz.write('%s,%8x,%8y,%8z'\'n%(xpoints,ypoints,0)')
```

to this:

```
xyz.write('%s,%8s,%8s,%8s\n' % (xpoints,ypoints,0))
```

Comment: but it doesn't work properly. the error is 'unsupported format character 'y' (0x79) at index 9'

Comment: @saberyoukawa: correct. I wasn't sure what you were trying to go for there. `%y` and `%z` are both illegal. I don't know exactly what format you want, but using `%s` might be good enough.

Comment: Dear Brayan, I wan to simulate transition from liquid to solid of Argon with molecular dynamics with python. can you help me?