# Writing to a file with xyz format with z=0

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write x points and y points in a trajectory file with the xyz format. But I am a

Comment: Could you show us some of your data?

Comment: Agree with @N.Wouda. You probably need to escape some '%' characters in your data.

Answer (score 3):

In your `%8y` the `y` isn't a valid [format character](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html). What you mean is `%8dy` so that you get `100y` in your output (of course, swap `d` for the right formatting you need). You got lucky with `x` as it maps to hex formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting with

```
'%s,%8x,%8y,%8z\n' % ('Ar',x[i],y[i],z)
```

is 'the old' formatting style in Python. [Reference](https://pyformat.info/)

Try something like this instead:

```
'{0:s},{1:f}x,{2:f}y,{3:f}z\n'.format('Ar',x[i],y[i],z)
```

*edit:* removed part to xyz.close()

Comment: Eh? The program's completion should implicitly flush buffered output.

Comment: Yeah sorry, was running in an continuous iPython console. And xyz.close() was in original post, I just didn't saw it the first time.

Comment: Dear Laenan, I wan to simulate transition from liquid to solid of Argon with molecular dynamics with python. can you help me?

Comment: In principle yes, but some more informations are needed: Like the Force Field you wanna use, the settings and what is the goal of the simulation, because there are various ways to do that. Beside that this is not the correct board for that, you could post your question to: [Chemistry Stackexchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) and refer to it in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680336/writing-to-a-file-with-xyz-format).